# PHP Codeigniter Form Validation (number)

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I'm trying to give a numeric input a range between 0 and 20

**this is the code :**

```
<div class=" col-md-9">
<?php
    echo form_input( array(
        "id"            => "artificial_intelligence",
        "name"          => "average_info_av_ia",
        "class"         => "form-control",
        "type"          => "number",
        "placeholder"   => lang( 'artificial_intelligence' ),
        "min"           => "0",
        "max"           => "20"
    ));
?>
</div>
```

but it only allow input : 0,1,2,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
and when i tap a number between 3 and 9 it goes to 20 
how ?

Comment: I'm going to add this as a comment and not an answer because I am not sure and I don't have time to test this right now, but you might want to try changing the "0" and "20" as strings, to just 0 and 20 as numbers.

Comment: i did , same issue

Comment: You can set validation using - `greater_than` and `less_than`. Refer 

(https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use range, then you can use **input type range** as shown below,

```
"type" => "range",
```

Or if you anyway use **input type number** , you need to check values with javascript to check it is between **1 to 20**. See below code

```
<div class=" col-md-12">
<?php
  echo form_input( array(
    "id"            => "artificial_intelligence",
    "name"          => "average_info_av_ia",
    "class"         => "form-control",
    "type"          => "number",
    "placeholder"   => lang( 'artificial_intelligence' ),
    "min"           => "0",
    "max"           => "20",
    "onchange"      => "handleChange(this);"
  ));
?>
</div>  
<script>
  function handleChange(input) {
    if (input.value < 0) input.value = 0;
    if (input.value > 20) input.value = 20;
  }
</script>
```